Get full responses from api call
Im trying to get a response from the Google Cloud Identity API and fill out a Google sheet with specific results such as policy name, setting name and values from the settings. The code is below and is working as I want it too. However im only getting 50 results from the API and I should be getting 228 results, which I believe is something to do with getting the next page of results. I've done some research online, but cant figure out how to get it to return more then 50 results. Any help appreciated!
function get_settings() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("07. settings api");

  const api_key = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('apikey');
  var url = "https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1beta1/policies?key=" + api_key;

  const params = {
    headers: {
      "method": "get",
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(response);
  var data = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(data);

  //console.log(json);

  var final=[];
  for (var a=0; a<json.policies.length; a++)
  {
    var name=json.policies[a].name;
    var setting=json.policies[a].setting.type;
    var value=json.policies[a].setting.value;
    final.push([name,setting,value])
  }
  
  settingsSheet.getRange(2,1,final.length,final[0].length).setValues(final);


}


How about modifying your showing script as follows?
Modified script:
It seems that the default value of pageSize is 50. This is the reason for your current issue. So, in this modification, in order to retrieve all items, I used pageSize and pageToken.
function get_settings() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("07. settings api");
  const api_key = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('apikey');


  const params = {
    headers: {
      "method": "get",
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  };
  let pageToken = "";
  var json = { policies: [] };
  do {
    const url = `https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1beta1/policies?key=${api_key}&pageSize=100&pageToken=${pageToken}&fields=*`;
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    const data = response.getContentText();
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj.policies.length > 0) {
      json.policies.push(...obj.policies);
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`${json.policies.length} items were obtained.`);
  console.log(`${json.policies.length} items were obtained.`);


  var final = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < json.policies.length; a++) {
    var name = json.policies[a].name;
    var setting = json.policies[a].setting.type;
    var value = json.policies[a].setting.value;
    final.push([name, setting, value])
  }
  settingsSheet.getRange(2, 1, final.length, final[0].length).setValues(final);
}

Reference:

Method: policies.list


That worked Tanaike, thanks for that. Hopefully last question on this topic, but the data pulled into the sheet for setting value is in the following format:
{allowedIpAddresses=[Ljava.lang.Object;@769f5fba}
That should be an IP address, but its not showing for some reason. All the other setting values are showing in {} format such as: {takeoutStatus=ENABLED}
Is there a way to remove the {} from the setting value and just show somthing like takeoutStatus=ENABLED instead?

@Mark Fraher Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. In your showing script, 3 values name, setting, value are retrieved. If your new issue is related to value, how about modifying final.push([name, setting, value]) to final.push([name, setting, JSON.stringify(value)])? But, I'm not sure whether this is a solution to your new question. I apologize for this.

Hi Tanaike, thats worked and I can see the values of the settings now. Cheers!

@Mark Fraher Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your new issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
